# Date not show each post wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to know how I can keep the date of the post from showing on blog of the pages. but date not show in each post.

url: ichooseapp.com/blog

```
<div class="tiemsec1">

            <div class="timetitle1"><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php get_the_date(); //the_date('d.m.y'); ?></a></div>

            <p>by <?php echo get_the_author(); ?> </p>

        </div>
```

can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

get_the_date(); function need to be echo;
as

> echo get_the_date();

why you are not using the_date() function that's not need to echo